# Can't install confluent helm chart on minikube

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, confluent-platform

I'm trying to use confluent helm chart following this link https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/tree/e17565cd5a6985a594155b12b08068cb5882e51f/charts/cp-kafka-connect but when I install it on minikube I got `ImagePullBackOff`

```
confluent-oss3-cp-control-center-5fc8c494c8-k25ps    0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          76m
confluent-oss3-cp-kafka-0                            0/2     ImagePullBackOff   0          76m
confluent-oss3-cp-kafka-connect-7849d49c47-jmmrn     0/2     ImagePullBackOff   0          76m
confluent-oss3-cp-kafka-rest-777cc4899b-zqcf9        0/2     ImagePullBackOff   0          76m
confluent-oss3-cp-ksql-server-567646677-b8lw4        0/2     ImagePullBackOff   0          76m
confluent-oss3-cp-schema-registry-6b8d69887d-5cmvt   0/2     ErrImagePull       0          76m
confluent-oss3-cp-zookeeper-0                        0/2     ImagePullBackOff   0          76m
```

Is there any solution to fix this problem ?

Comment: Could you please add `kubectl describe` of some of the pods to your question so we could see why they're imagepullbackoff and errimagepull? You used `helm install --name my-confluent cp-helm-charts` or you add something?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue after deleting minikube and reinstalling helm and the chart again.